# iframe content reloads when there is a DOM manipulation Angular

Tags: angular, iframe, angular2-changedetection

I have an iframe that is loaded dynamically when a specific condition is met.

```
      <div *ngIf="iframeData">
        <iframe [src]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(iframeData.iFrameUrl)" name="paymetricIFrame"></iframe>
      </div>
```

The issue I have is that whenever anything in the page - outside of the frame -  changes (Input text, select values, etc), the iFrame content reloads, and I can see all the scripts contained being reloaded in the network tab, and therefore what the user has filled in the iframe disappears.

I am suspecting the `ChangeDetectionStrategy` since the stack trace of the initiator of the call that loads the files for the iframe goes back to `viewRef._detectChanges` as you can see from the screenshot:

[image]

I tried to add `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` but that created other issues on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by creating a new component that contains only the iframe. I would still want to know why that solved the issue...

Comment: @fishbone thanks for referring that link! Good to see this solution worked for you as well!